# Capybara: fill_in: unable to find field

Tags: capybara

Code: https://github.com/jmopr/job-hunter/blob/master/scraper.rb

So i'm running a scraper on indeed.com but it seems to be unable to find the field q, which is the first field on the left. I'm 100% certain that the code is correct but i'm not sure why it isn't able to view the form. `save_and_open_page` CONFIRMS that it was able to view indeed.com successfully... yet is unable to locate the form.

Code:

```
def perform_search
# For indeed0
save_and_open_page
fill_in 'q', :with => @skillset
fill_in 'l', :with => @region
find('#fj').click
sleep(1)
end
```

Indeed.com HTML:

```
<input class="input_text" maxlength="512" size="31" aria-labelledby="what_label_top hidden_colon what_label_bot" name="q" autocomplete="off" id="what">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required portions/redirects of the page are loaded from 'indeed.com' rather than 'www.indeed.com' - Change your capybara-webkit configuration to allow `indeed.com`.

Additionally, if you want to know what the driver is actually seeing, you're generally better off using `save_and_open_screenshot` rather that `save_and_open_page` (The latter will show you the html structure but not how capybara-webkit has rendered it)

Comment: thank you. I figured it out on my own but stackoverflow doesn't let me post as often as I would like.

since you are here, i would like to ask you something. I've been getting inconsistent errors running the script, which makes debugging a real pain. Any idea why this happens? In one instance for example, the script fails to find the #fj (Find Jobs) button... but re-executing the script fixes the problem. Any idea what is happening? There are other inconsistent errors as well that are too long to fit in this comment section.

Comment: @AlannaMueller Glad you solved it, once you build up a small amount of reputation the rules relax.